# Как задать рабочую директорию для QProcess

Tags: c++, qprocess

Подскажите, как задать рабочую директорию для QProcess? У меня происходит вызов консольной утилиты 'sacd_extract' через QProcess, но эта утилита не поддерживает явного указания выходной директории, т.е. при запуске она создает файлы в той папке из которой была запущена.

```
QProcess *procedure_1 = new QProcess;

QStringList arguments;
arguments << preset.split(" ") << input_file;
procedure_1->start("sacd_extract", arguments);
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory

Comment: Спасибо! всё оказалось просто.